# Print the model values in collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, struct, uicollectionview

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    var liveModel = [LiveModel]()
    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return liveModel.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.imageViewer.image = UIImage(named: "\(liveModel[indexPath.row].image[0].src)")
        return cell
    }
}

struct LiveModel: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var image: [Image]
}

struct Image: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: Int
    var src: String
}
```

I have this model. I want to access "src" value from "Image" for collection view using indexpath. How can I do that?

I am fetching the images from API. I use model for that. I successfully access the value "id" & "name" from "LiveModel" but I can't understand how access the "src" value from "Image" model

Comment: `image` is an array so you will need something like `model.image[0].src` - Perhaps [edit] your question to add more code to show what you are trying to do.

Comment: let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        let model = liveModel[indexPath.row]
        print(model.image[0].src)
        return cell

Comment: Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to show the first image, and assuming there is always at least 1 image, then your line:

```
cell.imageViewer.image = UIImage(named: "\(liveModel[indexPath.row].image[0].src)")
```

is close. Just remove the unnecessary string interpolation.

```
cell.imageViewer.image = UIImage(named: liveModel[indexPath.row].image[0].src)
```

This code will crash if the given `liveModel` record has no images. So if that is a possibility you should code accordingly.

Also note that with a `UICollectionView` you should use the `item` property of `IndexPath`. Use `row` for `UITableView`. Though effectively they are the same.

Here's the updated method with all of the changes.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    if let imageSrc = liveMode[indexPath.item].image.first?.src {
        cell.imageViewer.image = UIImage(named: imageSrc)
    }

    return cell
}
```